# How to add a configuration file into an EAR using maven-ear-plugin

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I need to deploy the ehcache config file (an .xml file which must be placed in classpath) into my application EAR. As my application uses ehcache in several modules, I want to place the config file at EAR level.

In order to make it work in JBOSS EAP 6, I had to put the ehcache.xml file into:

```
EARFILE.ear
-----classes/ehcache.xml
```

And add this to the application.xml under:

```
<module>
   <java>classes</java>
</module>
```

The problem is that I package the whole EAR file with the maven-ear-plugin, and I've found no way to tell it to add the new module into application.xml. The "classes" folder and the .xml file are in the EAR, but I need to tell JBOSS to load it in the classpath.

There's a simpler way to achieve that without the adding a module in application.xml? I'm missing config in my pom's ear-plugin? Does it make sense to put an .xml config file at EAR level or should I put it inside one of my .war's?

Thanks!